# Left Shift Key on Dell wireless keyboard not working Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, dell, keyboard-layout, wireless-keyboards

I'm using [Dell Km117 Wireless Keyboard Mouse](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B01LOORNLY?ref_=pe_3025041_270609711_E_301_dt_1) along with newly installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I have a strange issue where I'm not able to use **Left Shift key** for purpose of navigation i.e. shortcuts such as `Ctrl+Shift+Tab` or `Alt+Shift+Tab` are not working but only with LEFT shift key. These shortcuts work fine with **Right shift key**.

So far I've tried doing updating everything using apt-get and tried changing keyboard profiles as shown in the attached image.

[Output of `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIuUD.png)

[Output of commands `cat /etc/default/keyboard` AND `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duuvk.png)

I tried setting it to:

- Dell
- Dell 101-key PC
- Dell USB Multimedia

I restarted the system after changing each time and it didn't work. [This](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-shift-keys-not-working-properly/) is the reference for why I tried the above solution.

I have US Keyboard layout and English US as language in settings. Please let me know if providing any other detail can help. I'm not sure why this kind of strange issue is occurring but it is driving me crazy. I can't think of a reason or find on the internet for why only right shift key is working completely fine but the left shift key is handicapped.

Please help me out here guys!

Comment: I see that your system wide keyboard layout is _English (India, with rupee)_ and not _English (US)_. OTOH I can't see how that would cause the issue you describe. There seem not to be any applicable XKB options either. So unfortunately I'm out of ideas. Hopefully someone else can provide a hint.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson not sure what happened. But I hadn't used the system for a while and came back to it just today. I did apt-get update and a reboot. It seems to be working fine now for some reason. :)